# In a string, add each HTML element with some property into a new arbitrary element with arbitrary value for arbitrary property

Tags: java, mapping

I have a string which contains this HTML code:

```
abc <h1><div style="color: rgb(190, 6, 6);">ABC <span style="color: rgb(0, 255, 6);">DEF</span></div></h1>
```

My program must detect that `color` has been used, so that it automatically adds the element (`div` and `span`) each into a new element `font`. It must work even if there are several elements which each contain a `color` rule, in a string where other HTML elements are added at left or right.

How could I do this?

The above code would become:

```
abc <h1><font color="rgb(190, 6, 6)"><div style="color: rgb(190, 6, 6);">ABC <font color="rgb(0, 255, 6);"><span style="color: rgb(0, 255, 6);">DEF</span></font></div></font></h1>
```

Comment: What you tried so far? Have you tried using regular expression to search and replace?

Comment: Hi Hari, I thought I could detect the first "<" appearing before the word "color", not present between double quotes. Thus I will be able to identify the opening tag. For html elements without ending tag it would be sufficient. But for htm elements with beginning and ending tags, it's not. What I want to do seems quite difficult. I thought there were some API or other.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regular expression for searching and replacing

```
pattern = "(<div[\s]+style=")(color:[\s]+rgb\([\d]+, [\d]+, [\d]+\))"

replace by "<font color=\"$2\">$1\"$2\"
```

This works for div. Similarly you can do it for span

Comment: Do you take into account the ending tag associated to this opening one? Perhaps I'm wrong but I don't see it.

Comment: I have not taken into account the ending tag. of course to make it more precise you can add that also

Comment: But to take the ending tag into account, one must take care of the contents of the element, and using regex only won't solve this problem.

Comment: By the way, I'm trying JSoup. I think it will solve the problem more efficiently than all we could invent :). I will publish my answer if what I'm trying works.